# Does "digital crafting agency" sound good and is it meaningful for a company's description?

Tags: phrase-requests, phrase-meaning

There are some web development studios who call themselves a "digital agency".

For our small team we're going to take a similar tagline, "digital crafting agency".

Does this sound okay to native speakers? Is it descriptive of a company who makes websites and (maybe) some other media things like games or apps?

Comment: Digital agency sounds like you are kind of a online graphics shop that doesn't really know what your business is.  Digital crafting agency is confusing and seems like you are trying to hard.

Comment: I was going to disagree with your premise because I hadn't heard that phrase, but then I did a web search and found that "digital agency" is actually used. Yuck.

Comment: I am in the "digital" business and it is used a lot but when I am vetting out a "digital agency" the range of what they do is all over the place.  It is a nonsense word that turns me off to the company right away.   The company I work for pays millions of $s a year to vendors like you.  People like me make the decisions.  Come up with something that is either unique or that specifically tells what you do.  Either way is fine with me.  Don't confuse me before I walk in the door because after I am turned off that first time I won't talk to you again.  Just trying to help you not to be rude.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. You may be interested in our companion site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). This question would be a better fit there.

Comment: @terdon Actually it would be better for the start-ups site.

Comment: I think this question is really a type of "writing advice", and is therefore Off Topic.

Comment: Since you asked . . . I think the use of "craft" and "crafting" to mean "creating", "developing" or "making" is overused and smacks of snobbery. FWIW. :-)

Comment: I wonder if it really matters what it sounds like "to the native speaker." Even if a native speaker furrowed a curious eyebrow in bewilderment, so long as your customer base understood the name, it might still be a good one. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, I wouldn't really know what to think of a "digital agency".  It doesn't convey any meaning, other than the assumption that the company is a web based company.

If someone where to tell me that Amazon was digital agency, I would convey the same meaning as if they had told me Mozilla was a digital agency.  The assumption being that all their business is conducted online (ie no brick and mortar stores).

Answer (score 2):

"Digital Crafting Agency" Is only slightly better in conveying what it is your company does over "Digital Agency".

"Digital Agency" could mean any sort of company that works with computers (Not even necessarily web-based, because every electronic display device this day with few exceptions is a "digital device").

Adding the word "Crafting" only further expands upon this description by saying you create some sort of product that is digital, which is quite a broad range of objects, even if we assume it is only a web-based product (and if we do assume that, then it encompasses every single web product that exists).

You would be better off advertizing your company by stating clearly the exact product that you offer.  If you offer a broad range of web-based services, you could call your company a "Web Development" company.  Or if you produce digital interactive devices such as mobile phones, you could refer to the precise object that you produce.

Depending on what your company actually makes, you have a plethora of different options for how to advertize your services.  But neither "Digital Agency" nor "Digital Crafting Agency" offers much in the way of explaining what it is your company does.

Answer (score 2):

Crafting sounds too close to the word "[Grafting](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grafting?s=t)", and if this is going to be something you say over the phone or on your voicemail "Thanks for calling Blark, the Digital Crafting Agency! Make it a great day!" people might mishear it and think you are a digital Grafting agency - not good.

Comment: I don't think that would happen but I love that you tied crafting to grafting! lol!

Comment: I don't always catch what people say over the phone, and I also have a lot of empathy for people who have to answer a business line and field those questions from people like me!

Comment: Wonders: _"How did I get on that grafting company's call list???"_

Answer (score 1):

Agencies are understood to employ Cratives to consult in the realization of your idea.

Digital is a horrid buzzword in this context, unless your company is being presented alongside  Modeling / Talent agencies, and Detective Agencies.

Crafting does something useful, `iff` you are akin somehow to Etsy.com
If not, it should be put in your motto.